# cleaning mysql text from line breaks

Tags: php

How would you go about removing extra line breaks for example:

```
text text text


text text
```

And i would like it to be this way

```
text text
text
```

i am already using nl2br($desc) in order for the line breaks to appear at all 
now how to i limit them to 1

Comment: Because his data is coming from mysql?

Comment: well i am using a mysql result which is why i have this problem

Comment: One way to remove 2 or 3 etc breaks: `$txt = str_replace(array("<br><br>", "<br><br><br>"), null, $txt)`.

Comment: Fix the problem when you *put* data into the db. Correcting it like this is doing everything backwards and ignoring the actual error.

Comment: php is the only language relevant to the actual problem though - the mysql query is just the content of a string (which could be any other string with line breaks - like the example)

Comment: When are you escaping the string so that you don't accidentally inject Javscript from your user's data into the output?

Comment: i agree bos will think about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before using `nl2br()` replace all sequences of carriage return or new line characters with a single newline:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', "\n", $desc);
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/zn2oA)

Comment: Mark, you can revert the edit by click the edited x mins ago link

Answer (score 0):

after `nl2br()` do:

```
$desc = preg_replace('#(<br[ ]?[\/]?>[\r\n]*)+#','<br/>',$desc);
```

Comment: nope it doesn't work probably because the line breaks are '\n' & '\r' which extra's should also be removed and left only one

Comment: you said that you were using nl2br though :s

Comment: @Mikey: You can use ideone to test your code to see if it works or not: http://ideone.com/EadRZ